# Mocking virtual members in Moq

Tags: c#, moq

For unit testing, I'm using NUnit 2.6 and Moq 4.0. There's a particular case concerning virtual members where Moq's proxy objects don't relay method calls to the actual implementation (probably by design). For instance, if I had a class...

```
public class MyClass {
    protected virtual void A() {
        /* ... */
    }

    protected virtual void B(...) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

...and I use Moq to override `GetSomethingElse`'s `A()` method in my test fixture...

```
var mock = new Mock<MyClass>();
mock.Protected().Setup("A").Callback(SomeSortOfCallback);
```

...using the mock's `A` method works splendidly; however, if anything in said method would call not-mocked method `B`, the method will do nothing and/or return default values, even if an actual implementation exists in `MyClass`.

Is there a way to work around this? Am I using Moq wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Manny

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set `mock.CallBase = true` and you should be good to go.

Comment: what if you still want to mock other methods?

Comment: @LouisRhys Pretty sure this doesn't interfere with it - if you explicitly mock something the `CallBase` setting never comes into play.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var systemUnderTest = new Moq.Mock<ProcessBulkData> { CallBase = true };
 systemUnderTest.Setup(s => s.MethodName(...)).Returns(...);
 var actual=systemUnderTest.Object.BulkInsert(...);
```

Comment: It's better to include some explanation of the code along with your answer.